# class com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper is loading from from multiple locations

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jackson, build.gradle, jackson-databind

I am puzzled to solve this com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper error with Java 11. I want to use XmlMapper only from jackson dependency and that's why excluded from springboot starter web , still cannot figure how to resolve it's dependency. providing  as much details as possible -

**build.gradle**

```
group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        
    }
    jaxb
    fatJar
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-databind'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-annotations'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-xml', version: '2.12.2'
    
    compile("com.newrelic.logging:logback:2.0")
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.4'
    jaxb (
        'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.3.1',
        'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.1',
        'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.3'
    )
}
```

**dependency hierarchy**

```
+--- com.newrelic.logging:logback:2.0
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web -> 2.4.5
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.4.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.4.5
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.6
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.6
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.6
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.6
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.6
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.4.5
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.4.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.4.5
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.13.3
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.3
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.30
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.27
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.4.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.4.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.6
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.11.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.11.4
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.11.4
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.4.5
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.45
|    |    +--- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:3.0.3
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.45
|    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.45
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.6 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.6
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.6 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.6 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.6 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.6 (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.6 (*)
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator -> 2.4.5
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.4.5 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:2.4.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:2.4.5
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.4.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.4.5 (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.4.5 (*)
|    \--- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.6.6
|         \--- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:2.1.12
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.12.2
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.4
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.4
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.4 (*)
|    |    +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2 -> 2.3.3
|    |    |    \--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.2
|    |    \--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1 -> 1.2.2
|    +--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2.1
|    +--- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.2.4
|    |    \--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2.1
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.12.2
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.12.2 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
+--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.4
|    +--- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2
|    \--- javax.activation:activation:1.1
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test -> 2.4.5
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.4.5 (*)
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.4.5
     |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.4.5 (*)
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.4.5
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.4.5 (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.4.5 (*)
     |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.4.5 (*)
     +--- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.4.0
     |    +--- net.minidev:json-smart:2.3
     |    |    \--- net.minidev:accessors-smart:1.2
     |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.4
     |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
     +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3 (*)
     +--- org.assertj:assertj-core:3.18.1
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2
     +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1
     |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1
     |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1 (c)
     |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1 (c)
     |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.1 (c)
     |    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.1 (c)
     |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1
     |    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1 (*)
     |    |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
     |    |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
     |    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.1
     |    |         +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1 (*)
     |    |         \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
     |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.1
     |         +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1 (*)
     |         +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
     |         \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1 (*)
     +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.6.28
     |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.18 -> 1.10.22
     |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.10.18 -> 1.10.22
     |    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:3.1
     +--- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.6.28
     |    \--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.6.28 (*)
     +--- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.5.0
     |    \--- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:0.0.20131108.vaadin1
     +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
     +--- org.springframework:spring-test:5.3.6
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
     \--- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:2.7.0

testCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
No dependencies

testImplementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test (n)

testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
+--- com.newrelic.logging:logback:2.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.1 -> 2.11.4
|    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.0 -> 1.2.3
|    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.0 -> 1.2.3
|    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    \--- com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-api:5.6.0
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web -> 2.4.5
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.4.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.4.5
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.6
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.6
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.6
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.6
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.6
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.4.5
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.4.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.4.5
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.13.3
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.3
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.30
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.27
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.4.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.4.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.6
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.11.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.11.4
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.4
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.4
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.4
|    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.4
|    |    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.4
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.11.4
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.4.5
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.45
|    |    +--- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:3.0.3
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.45
|    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.45
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.6 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.6
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.6 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.6 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.6 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.6 (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.6 (*)
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator -> 2.4.5
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.4.5 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:2.4.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.11.4 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:2.4.5
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.4.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.4.5 (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.4.5 (*)
|    \--- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.6.6
|         +--- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:2.1.12
|         \--- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:2.0.3
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.12.2
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.4 (*)
|    |    +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2 -> 2.3.3
|    |    |    \--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.2
|    |    \--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1 -> 1.2.2
|    +--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2.1
|    +--- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.2.4
|    |    \--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2.1
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.12.2
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.12.2 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4 (c)
+--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.4
|    +--- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2
|    \--- javax.activation:activation:1.1
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test -> 2.4.5
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.4.5 (*)
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.4.5
     |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.4.5 (*)
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.4.5
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.4.5 (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.4.5 (*)
     |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.4.5 (*)
     +--- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.4.0
     |    +--- net.minidev:json-smart:2.3
     |    |    \--- net.minidev:accessors-smart:1.2
     |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.4
     |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
     +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3 (*)
     +--- org.assertj:assertj-core:3.18.1
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2
     +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1
     |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1
     |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1 (c)
     |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1 (c)
     |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.1 (c)
     |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.1 (c)
     |    |    +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.1 (c)
     |    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.7.1 (c)
     |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1
     |    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1 (*)
     |    |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
     |    |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
     |    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.1
     |    |         +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1 (*)
     |    |         \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
     |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.1
     |    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1 (*)
     |    |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
     |    |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1 (*)
     |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.1
     |         +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1 (*)
     |         +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
     |         +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.7.1
     |         |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1 (*)
     |         |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
     |         |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
     |         |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.1 (*)
     |         \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1 (*)
     +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.6.28
     |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.18 -> 1.10.22
     |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.10.18 -> 1.10.22
     |    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:3.1
     +--- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.6.28
     |    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.6.28 (*)
     |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2 -> 5.7.1 (*)
     +--- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.5.0
     |    \--- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:0.0.20131108.vaadin1
     +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
     +--- org.springframework:spring-test:5.3.6
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.6 (*)
     \--- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:2.7.0
```

**Error while running the boot app -**

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:175)

The following method did not exist:

    'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MutableCoercionConfig com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()'

The method's class, com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/user1/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.12.2/dac1d21b5fe602d492273d35eb28918a91fc5412/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.12.2.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper: file:/C:/Users/user1/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.12.2/dac1d21b5fe602d492273d35eb28918a91fc5412/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.12.2.jar
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper: file:/C:/Users/user1/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.11.4/5d9f3d441f99d721b957e3497f0a6465c764fad4/jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec: file:/C:/Users/user1/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.11.4/593f7b18bab07a76767f181e2a2336135ce82cc4/jackson-core-2.11.4.jar
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeCodec: file:/C:/Users/user1/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.11.4/593f7b18bab07a76767f181e2a2336135ce82cc4/jackson-core-2.11.4.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper
```

Comment: spring boot already contains jackson, what happens if you remove    'implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-xml', version: '2.12.2' for the dependencies?

Comment: I have tried this..but then my application don't find the XmlMapper class then. It is not included in the default transitive dependency if we only use spring-boot starter web

Comment: do you remove the exclude group lines as well?

Comment: Yes ofcourse.. otherwise it won't make sense.. i would reqst you to check once to import xmlmapper class by only using spring-boot starter web. I think you won't be able to import the class

Comment: what version of gradle are you using, I can't even build the project with your build.gradle

Comment: 6.9 sir. Should i give you the complete gradle..i have only given the dependency part

Comment: I can run the application with that dependency configuration in Gradle build file. And also serializing of objects into XML works with XmlMapper. Did you rebuild the application? 'gradlew clean build' ? Or try to clean dependency cache in your home./gradlew directory?

Comment: I tried all these with no luck.. may i know which gradle version did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you explicitly need version 2.12.2 of jackson-dataformat-xml?

**Problem**

jackson-dataformat-xml:2.12.2 is not compatible with jackson dependencies 2.11.4. Spring Boot overwrites Jackson dependencies that are not specified other way in dependencies block or in dependencyManagement.

**Solution**

If you don't need 2.12.2 then just define the jackson-dataformat-xml as following:

```
  implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-xml'
```

then resolved version will be

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml -> 2.11.4
```

which will be compatible with all other Jackson components and you will not be getting this exception anymore. Always try to check the dependencies of Jackson and make sure all are aligned.

You see for example if you run 'gradlew dependencies' and you get following result it's bad:

```
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.12.2
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.2 -> 2.11.4
```

versions of Jackson are not properly aligned. With managing Gradle dependencies you have to make sure you aligne them, that means upgrading or downgrading them.

If you really need explicitly 2.12.2 then you should also upgrade Spring Boot version which contains newer version.

You can specify version of Spring Boot in following way:

```
dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.0'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you call whole dataformat library when you only need XMLMapper?

I found this workaround using Spring, as I only needed XMLMapper:

Get a reference to the message converter, in declarations:

```
private final MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter msgConverter;
```

and later just refer to it from it's parent: ObjectMapper

```
    ObjectMapper xmlMapper = xmlConverter.getObjectMapper();
```

In that way you shouldn't get into the described dependency issue.

So, you only need to import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper